# how I may query or check the database connection every 15 seconds to check for any updates and show notification to user if it can connect or not?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a wpf(c#) that is currently connected to a database. Does anyone have an idea how I may query or check the database(SQL Server 2008) connection every 15 seconds to check for any updates and show notification to user if it can connect or not? 
Any code/information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by updates? Do you want to requery and see changes to ?

Comment: i want to check the the database connection if can connect or not? And show notification to user every 15 seconds.

Comment: How many users will you have?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen more then 50 user.

Comment: So you want to create more than 200 requests a second to check if the server is still there? What if it isn't, can the user do something about it? If not, does it matter than that it is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx), that provides a notice when something changes in a certain query.

Answer (score 0):

To test for changes in data passively, use SQLDependency as already suggested. Otherwise you need to implement a timer which runs asynchronously and polls the database, comparing with the last result.

```
 private async Task PollDb()
    {
        int lastCount = -1;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(15000);    // 15 second interval
            var newRecord = await Task.Factory.StartNew <ICollection<object>>(p =>
            {
                /* Get results here */
                return new List<object>();
            });

            if(newRecord.Count() != lastCount)
            {
                // Update app
            }
            lastCount = newRecord.Count();
        }
    }
```

If you just want to check the database is responding without the burden of a heavy query, just execute a query 'SELECT GETDATE()'